# Java regex, find text inside

Tags: java, regex, expression

I need to find some string in text after keyword in inside brackets first occurrence.
This is the text example:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
>   sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
>    **=== FIRST KEYWORD ===** veniam,
>   **{{ text need to get }}** ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
>   ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
>    dolor in reprehenderit {{in voluptate velit esse cillum}} dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
>   culpa qui officia {{deserunt mollit anim }}id est laborum

So I need get text inside the brackets after **first keyword**.

I tried many combination but the best was that I received the text from last brackets not first. With this exp I got text after keywords `(?<==== FIRST KEYWORD ===).(.|\n)*` 
But with finding first text in brackets I didn't succeed.

UPD: Thank you all, but answer from Bohemian not work for my corpus.
This answer :

```
"(?<==== FIRST KEYWORD ===)[^{]*\\{\\{([^}]*)\\}\\}"
```

works, but I don't see it now. So I cannot say thanks to that guy who wrote this, I don't remember.

Comment: Can there ever be single braces in your text besides the double braces used for delimiting your search text?

Comment: I have delimiter with two braces {{ }}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1:** If you want the `{{text AND the braces}}`

```
String ResultString = null;
try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("=== FIRST KEYWORD ===[^{]*?(\\{\\{(?:.(?!}}))*.}})", Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
    if (regexMatcher.find()) {
        ResultString = regexMatcher.group(1);
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

**Option 2:** If you want to match the {{ `text but NOT the braces` }}

```
String ResultString = null;
try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("=== FIRST KEYWORD ===[^{]*?\\{\\{((?:.(?!}}))*.)}}", Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
    if (regexMatcher.find()) {
        ResultString = regexMatcher.group(1);
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This code extracts your target:

```
String target = input.replaceAll("(?s).*?=== FIRST KEYWORD ===.*?\\{\\{(.*?)\\}\\}.*", "$1");
```

The important part of the regex is the use of a *reluctant* quantifier `.*?`, which will stop consuming input at the first available match (not skipping over it to a subsequent match).

#### Edit:

Note (thanks to [@guido](https://stackoverflow.com/users/389099/guido) for pointing this out) that the *dotall* flag `(?s)` has been added, which allows the dot matches to run across lines - required when working with multi-line input.

---

Some test code, using an abbreviated form of your example:

```
String input = "one two === FIRST KEYWORD === three {{xxx}} four {{yyy}} five";
String target = input.replaceAll("(?s).*?=== FIRST KEYWORD ===.*?\\{\\{(.*?)\\}\\}.*", "$1");
System.out.println(target);
```

Output:

```
xxx
```

Comment: +1 since this will not be tripped when there is a single `{` preceding the `{{`, as compared to other solutions.